# why doesn't federal reserve services website have all routing numbers?

Tags: usa, bank

https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/fpddir.txt contains a list of bank routing numbers but there's at least one that doesn't appear in that list: 111000025 (from https://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/manage/faq-routing-numbers.go if you select Texas).

https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=111000025 shows it as well. Given that it seems like the frbservices.org site ought to be showing it even tho it isn't?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, [here is a question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4034/1511) that discusses the source of this data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GitHub Repo [FedACHdir](https://github.com/gatepay/FedACHdir) that contains what I think is the same text file and also the specific routing number you are looking for:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gatepay/FedACHdir/master/FedACHdir.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the wrong file. Try this one: https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt